# Jpa 2.0 - EntityManager.find (SomeEntity.class,PK) need to fill Descriminator value to key

Tags: java, jpa

I have a problem, I have two entity Job and JobPK

```
Job class looks like this sample code :

@Entity
@IdClass(JobPK.class)
@Table(name="JOB")
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="JOB_TYPE")

public abstract class Job implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name="FOLDER_ID")
private BigDecimal folderId;

@Id
@ColumnDefinition(position = 1)
private String name;

@Column(name="JOB_TYPE",insertable=false,updatable=false)   
private String jobType;
...
}
```

and JobPk :

```
public class JobPK implements Serializable {    

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3266336718203527905L;

@Column(name="JOB_TYPE",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private String jobType;

@Id
private String name;

@Id
@Column(name="FOLDER_ID")
private BigDecimal folderId;
......
}
```

I have two class which extends Job : CalculatingJob and ImportingJob
Now I wont to use :

```
getEntityManager().find(CalculatingJob.class, new JobPK    (BigDecimal.valueOf(folderId),name))
```

and I have problem because I must fill i JobPK descriminator value field. If I don't do that I've got Null Pointer Exception. Descriminator value is in key by default I think but I don't want put information about descriminator value explicite during JobPk creating. I thought that Entity which extends from Job will fill this field automaticaly. Any Idea to bypass this problem, maybe I can get Annotation @DescriminatorVale  from CalculatingJob and then put into constructor JobPk

Thanks for Help

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration for Hierarchy structure

Job.java

```
@Table(name = "JOB")
@Inheritance
@IdClass(JobPK.class)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "JOB_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Job implements java.io.Serializable {

}
```

CalculatingJob.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CalculatingJob")
public class CalculatingJob extends Job {

}
```

ImportingJob.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ImportingJob")
public class ImportingJob extends Job {

}
```

JobPK.java

```
public class JobPK implements Serializable {    

}
```

The discriminator value is entered by hibernate.